# How to convert date : Sat Sep 26 00:15:00 2020 in YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS' format in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, date

`Sep 26 00:15:00 2020` can be converted as below ,but how can I convert Sat

```
SELECT 
  TO_CHAR(
    TO_DATE('Sep 26 00:15:00','Mon DD HH24:MI:SS')
  , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
  )
FROM dual;
```

> ORA-01843: not a valid month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Sep" (September) isn't recognized by your database's language.

Mine speaks Croatian so this query doesn't work for me either:

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR( TO_DATE('Sep 26 00:15:00','Mon DD HH24:MI:SS') , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) FROM dual;
SELECT TO_CHAR( TO_DATE('Sep 26 00:15:00','Mon DD HH24:MI:SS') , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) FROM dual
                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

One option is to alter session and set language to English:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_language = 'english';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR( TO_DATE('Sep 26 00:15:00','Mon DD HH24:MI:SS') , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) FROM dual;

TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('SE
-------------------
2020-09-26 00:15:00

SQL>
```

---

Another option is to include that information into the `TO_DATE` function:

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR( TO_DATE('Sep 26 00:15:00','Mon DD HH24:MI:SS', 'nls_date_language = english') , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) FROM dual;

TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('SE
-------------------
2020-09-26 00:15:00

SQL>
```

---

If you want to include day's name into the result, use appropriate format mask, e.g.

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR( TO_DATE('Sep 26 00:15:00','Mon DD HH24:MI:SS') , 'Day, YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) FROM dual;

TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('SEP2600:15:00','MONDDHH24:MI:SS'),'DAY,Y
---------------------------------------------------------
Saturday , 2020-09-26 00:15:00

SQL>
```

As you insist on `Sat` (for "Saturday") and - for some reason - don't want to check valid format masks yourself, then

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR( TO_DATE('Sep 26 00:15:00','Mon DD HH24:MI:SS') , 'Dy, YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) FROM dual;

TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('SEP2600:15:00','
---------------------------------
Sat, 2020-09-26 00:15:00

SQL>
```

Comment: what about Sat value

Comment: Dy instead of Day.

Comment: SELECT TO_CHAR( TO_DATE('Sat Sep 26 00:15:00','Dy Mon DD HH24:MI:SS') , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) FROM dual;

Comment: OK; query you just posted (as a comment) *works* correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Dy` format model:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         TO_DATE(
           'Sat Sep 26 00:15:00',
           'Dy Mon DD HH24:MI:SS',
           'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = English'
         ),
         'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
       ) AS formatted_date
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> | FORMATTED_DATE      |
> | :------------------ |
> | 2020-09-26 00:15:00 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a43484a12e4931459147352d935155af)*